# recursive lua function always returns nil

Tags: lua, neovim

alright this is probably a stupid mistake but I cant find it.

I am trying to iterate over a treesitter node to find the parent node i need.

```
local function getParent(node)

    local type_text = node:type()
    print(type_text, "node type")


    if type_text == "variable_declaration" then
        return 1
    end

    print("RUNNING AGAIN?")
    getParent(node:parent())
end

local outp = getParent(node_at_cursor, 0)
print(outp, "outp")
```

the output:

```
identifier node type 0
RUNNING AGAIN?
variable_list node type 1
RUNNING AGAIN?
assignment_statement node type 2
RUNNING AGAIN?
variable_declaration node type 3
nil outp
```

i don't understand why the return value is always nil. it clearly stops at some point, i see that from the print statements. The function enters the if block and should return 1.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the recursive call.

```lua
local function getParent(node)

    local type_text = node:type()
    print(type_text, "node type")


    if type_text == "variable_declaration" then
        return 1
    end

    print("RUNNING AGAIN?")
    return getParent(node:parent())
end
```

Comment: im retarded. thanks for your reply. haha -ill mark it as accepted once the delay is over